# odbc binding to datetime column fails on Linux but works on Windows

Tags: c++, sql-server, linux, windows, odbc

Our C++ code on Windows uses ODBC to talk to SQL Server.
We are in the process of porting to Linux and
getting this ODBC error for a datetime Stored Procedure argument.

**Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding.**

Googling that error says to set scale to 3 on the ODBC bind.
We do that and it works on Windows but not Linux.

Here is a semi small code sample that reproduces the problem.
The sample is 330 lines of C++ and 100 lines of SQL.
(The original is 1000 times bigger.)

It seems to be related to a blob SP argument.
datetime before the blob work, and those after the blob fail.
I tried making a 3 column test table with (datetime, blob, datetime)
but the problem did not happen.

On Windows this test inserts 820 rows while
on Linux it inserts 700 because 120 fail.

Windows has "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server".
Linux is Ubuntu 20.04, unixODBC 2.3.7, ODBC 17.7

Create a database name bgb_test2.
Create a DSN named bgb8_sql2016 pointing to DB server.
Add SQL user 'bgb' with password 'Abc-123'.
Or change the code as you like.

SQL code

```
    USE [bgb_test2]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_TTemporalAccounts_ins]    Script Date: 5/28/2021 11:46:19 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TTemporalAccounts](
    [acctId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [rowClassifier] [char](16) NULL,
    [grpClassifier] [char](16) NULL,
    [LAD] [datetime] NULL,
    [LAPD] [datetime] NULL,
    [NAD] [datetime] NULL,
    [AccountBlob] [text] NULL,
    [StatementDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [postBalance] [money] NULL,
    [Balance] [money] NULL,
    [CountDe] [int] NULL,
    [bucketMTD1] [money] NULL,
    [bucketMTD2] [money] NULL,
    [bucketMTD3] [money] NULL,
    [bucketCTD1] [money] NULL,
    [bucketCTD2] [money] NULL,
    [bucketCTD3] [money] NULL,
    [parent01ATID] [int] NULL,
    [parent01AID] [int] NULL,
    [parent02ATID] [int] NULL,
    [parent02AID] [int] NULL,
    [parent03ATID] [int] NULL,
    [parent03AID] [int] NULL,
    [VisaInterestRate] [money] NULL,
    [VisaLateCharge] [money] NULL,
    [VisaParam1] [money] NULL,
    [VisaParam2] [money] NULL,
    [VisaParam3] [money] NULL,
    [VisaParam4] [money] NULL,
    [VisaParam5] [money] NULL,
    [VisaParam6] [money] NULL,
    [VisaParam7] [money] NULL,
    [VisaParam8] [money] NULL,
    [tpyNAD] [datetime] NULL,
    [tpyLAD] [datetime] NULL,
    [tpyBlob] [text] NULL,
    [param_sig] [int] NULL,
    [param_state] [varchar](171) NULL,
    [param_lcd] [datetime] NULL,
    [param_fvt] [datetime] NULL,
    [_paramlvt] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [csPk_TTemporalAccounts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [acctId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TTemporalAccounts_ins] (
@acctId int, @rowClassifier char (16), @grpClassifier char (16),
@LAD datetime, @LAPD datetime, @NAD datetime,
@AccountBlob text, @StatementDate datetime, @postBalance money,
@Balance money, @CountDe int,
@bucketMTD1 money, @bucketMTD2 money, @bucketMTD3 money,
@bucketCTD1 money, @bucketCTD2 money, @bucketCTD3 money,
@parent01ATID int, @parent01AID int,
@parent02ATID int, @parent02AID int,
@parent03ATID int, @parent03AID int,
@VisaInterestRate money, @VisaLateCharge money,
@VisaParam1 money, @VisaParam2 money, @VisaParam3 money,
@VisaParam4 money, @VisaParam5 money, @VisaParam6 money,
@VisaParam7 money, @VisaParam8 money,
@tpyNAD datetime, @tpyLAD datetime, @tpyBlob text,
@param_sig int, @param_state varchar (171),
@param_lcd datetime, @param_fvt datetime, @_paramlvt datetime
) AS SET NOCOUNT ON; SET ANSI_NULLS ON; SET ANSI_PADDING ON; SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON; SET ARITHABORT ON; SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON; SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;
INSERT INTO TTemporalAccounts ( [acctId], [rowClassifier], [grpClassifier], [LAD], [LAPD], [NAD],
[AccountBlob], [StatementDate], [postBalance], [Balance], [CountDe], [bucketMTD1], [bucketMTD2], [bucketMTD3],
[bucketCTD1], [bucketCTD2], [bucketCTD3], [parent01ATID], [parent01AID], [parent02ATID], [parent02AID],
[parent03ATID], [parent03AID], [VisaInterestRate], [VisaLateCharge],
[VisaParam1], [VisaParam2], [VisaParam3], [VisaParam4], [VisaParam5], [VisaParam6], [VisaParam7], [VisaParam8],
[tpyNAD], [tpyLAD], [tpyBlob],
[param_sig], [param_state], [param_lcd], [param_fvt], [_paramlvt])
VALUES ( @acctId, @rowClassifier, @grpClassifier, @LAD, @LAPD, @NAD, @AccountBlob, @StatementDate,
@postBalance, @Balance, @CountDe, @bucketMTD1, @bucketMTD2, @bucketMTD3, @bucketCTD1, @bucketCTD2, @bucketCTD3,
@parent01ATID, @parent01AID, @parent02ATID, @parent02AID, @parent03ATID, @parent03AID,
@VisaInterestRate, @VisaLateCharge,
@VisaParam1, @VisaParam2, @VisaParam3, @VisaParam4, @VisaParam5, @VisaParam6, @VisaParam7, @VisaParam8,
@tpyNAD, @tpyLAD, @tpyBlob,
@param_sig, @param_state, @param_lcd, @param_fvt, @_paramlvt) 
GO
```

C++ code

```
#ifdef WIN32
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 1 
#endif
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN     
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sal.h>
#endif

#include <string.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

// Binding to datetime column is failing on Linux

RETCODE
BBCheckForInfo(SQLSMALLINT HandleType, SQLHANDLE h, RETCODE rc, const char* api, const char* name = 0)
{
    SQLCHAR       SqlState[6], Msg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    SQLINTEGER    NativeError;
    SQLSMALLINT   i, MsgLen;
    SQLRETURN     rc2;
    long cpu_time = 0;
    long elapsed_time = 0;
    // Support growing these if needed
    SQLCHAR* pMsg = Msg;
    size_t MsgAlloc = sizeof(Msg);

    if (name == 0) name = "";
    // Print any errors or warnings.
    if (rc != SQL_SUCCESS) {
        // Get the status records.
        i = 1;
        while ((rc2 = SQLGetDiagRec(HandleType, h, i, SqlState, &NativeError, pMsg, MsgAlloc, &MsgLen)) == SQL_SUCCESS || rc2 == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
            if (rc2 == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
                printf("Msg[] too small, need %d bytes (have %d)\n", MsgLen, MsgAlloc);
                if (pMsg != Msg) delete[] pMsg;
                MsgAlloc = MsgLen + 100;
                pMsg = new SQLCHAR[MsgAlloc + 10];
                // Do not increment i so we retry getting the last error message
                continue;
            }
            i++;

            printf("Query %s API %s() Name %s State %s Native %d Msg %s\n",
                name,
                api,
                name,
                SqlState, NativeError, Msg);
        } // while
        if (rc2 != SQL_NO_DATA) {
            printf("SQLGetDiagRec(%s) name %s returned %d\n", api, name, rc2);
        }
    } // if

    if (pMsg != Msg) delete[] pMsg;
    pMsg = 0;

    if (rc == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) rc = SQL_SUCCESS;
    return rc;
}

enum class CI_type {
    CI_int,
    CI_char16,
    CI_datetime,
    CI_text,
    CI_money,
    CI_varchar171,
    //  CI_end
};

#define N_COL 41
struct ColInfo {
    const char* name;
    enum CI_type type;
} g_ColInfoArray[N_COL] = {
    "acctId", CI_type::CI_int,
    "rowClassifier", CI_type::CI_char16,
    "grpClassifier", CI_type::CI_char16,
    "LAD", CI_type::CI_datetime,
    "LAPD", CI_type::CI_datetime,
    "NAD", CI_type::CI_datetime,
    "AccountBlob", CI_type::CI_text,
    "StatementDate", CI_type::CI_datetime,
    "postBalance", CI_type::CI_money,
    "Balance", CI_type::CI_money,
    "CountDe", CI_type::CI_int,
    "bucketMTD1", CI_type::CI_money,
    "bucketMTD2", CI_type::CI_money,
    "bucketMTD3", CI_type::CI_money,
    "bucketCTD1", CI_type::CI_money,
    "bucketCTD2", CI_type::CI_money,
    "bucketCTD3", CI_type::CI_money,
    "parent01ATID", CI_type::CI_int,
    "parent01AID", CI_type::CI_int,
    "parent02ATID", CI_type::CI_int,
    "parent02AID", CI_type::CI_int,
    "parent03ATID", CI_type::CI_int,
    "parent03AID", CI_type::CI_int,
    "VisaInterestRate", CI_type::CI_money,
    "VisaLateCharge", CI_type::CI_money,
    "VisaParam1", CI_type::CI_money,
    "VisaParam2", CI_type::CI_money,
    "VisaParam3", CI_type::CI_money,
    "VisaParam4", CI_type::CI_money,
    "VisaParam5", CI_type::CI_money,
    "VisaParam6", CI_type::CI_money,
    "VisaParam7", CI_type::CI_money,
    "VisaParam8", CI_type::CI_money,
    "tpyNAD", CI_type::CI_datetime,
    "tpyLAD", CI_type::CI_datetime,
    "tpyBlob", CI_type::CI_text,
    "param_sig", CI_type::CI_int,
    "param_state", CI_type::CI_varchar171,
    "param_lcd", CI_type::CI_datetime,
    "param_fvt", CI_type::CI_datetime,
    "_paramlvt", CI_type::CI_datetime,
    //  { 0, CI_type::CI_end }
};

void
main()
{
    std::string ConStr;
    ConStr += ";DSN=bgb8_sql2016"; // change
    ConStr += ";DATABASE=bgb_test2";
    ConStr += ";UID=bgb;PWD=Abc-123"; // change
    ConStr += ";APP=DBB";
    //  const char* computername = dbbGetenv("COMPUTERNAME");
    ConStr += ";WSID=host";
    //  ConStr += computername;
    ConStr += ";AutoTranslate=no";

    SQLHENV hEnv;
    int rc;
    rc = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);

    rc = SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv, rc, "SQLSetEnvAttr", "SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION");

    SQLHDBC hDbc;
    rc = SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);
    rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv, rc, "SQLAllocConnect()");

    //  rc = SQLSetConnectAttr(hDbc, SQL_COPT_SS_BCP, (void*)SQL_BCP_ON, SQL_IS_INTEGER);
    //  BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc, rc, "SQLSetConnectAttr", "SQL_COPT_SS_BCP");

    short outlen = 0;
    UCHAR outbuf[2048];
    rc = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, (UCHAR*)ConStr.c_str(), ConStr.length(), outbuf, sizeof(outbuf), &outlen, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc, rc, "SQLDriverConnect()");

    SQLHSTMT hstmt;
    SQLAllocStmt(hDbc, &hstmt);
    rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc, rc, "SQLAllocStmt()");

    int skey = 0;
    for (int rows = 0; rows < 20; rows++) {
        // for x in 0 .. 2^N_COL-1
        // (c in x) means set col, else NULL
        // Inserting 2^41 rows may hit practical limitations (BOOM)
        for (int nn = 0; nn < N_COL; nn++) {
            void* mem[N_COL];
            for (int c = 0; c < N_COL; c++) {
                // Set PK and column nn to values, rest are NULL
                SQLHSTMT        StatementHandle = hstmt;
                SQLUSMALLINT    ParameterNumber = c + 1;
                SQLSMALLINT     InputOutputType = SQL_PARAM_INPUT;
                SQLSMALLINT     ValueType = -1;
                SQLSMALLINT     ParameterType = -1;
                SQLULEN         ColumnSize = 0;
                SQLSMALLINT     DecimalDigits = 0;
                SQLPOINTER      ParameterValuePtr = 0;
                SQLLEN          BufferLength = 0;
                SQLLEN* StrLen_or_IndPtr = 0;

                switch (g_ColInfoArray[c].type) {
                case CI_type::CI_int:
                    ValueType = SQL_C_DEFAULT;
                    ParameterType = SQL_INTEGER;
                    break;
                case CI_type::CI_char16:
                    ValueType = SQL_C_CHAR;
                    ParameterType = SQL_CHAR;
                    ColumnSize = 16;
                    break;
                case CI_type::CI_datetime:
                    ValueType = SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP;
                    ParameterType = SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP;
                    ColumnSize = 23;
                    DecimalDigits = 3;
                    break;
                case CI_type::CI_text:
                    ValueType = SQL_C_CHAR;
                    ParameterType = SQL_LONGVARCHAR;
                    ColumnSize = 100;
                    break;
                case CI_type::CI_money:
                    ValueType = SQL_C_CHAR;
                    ParameterType = SQL_VARCHAR;
                    break;
                case CI_type::CI_varchar171:
                    ValueType = SQL_C_CHAR;
                    ParameterType = SQL_CHAR;
                    ColumnSize = 171;
                    break;
                }
                // (c == 0) is Primary Key
                int value = 5;
                if (c == 0) value = skey++;
                if (c == 0 || c == nn) {
                    switch (g_ColInfoArray[c].type) {
                    case CI_type::CI_int:
                        {
                            SQLINTEGER* p = new SQLINTEGER;
                            mem[c] = p;
                            *p = value;
                        }
                        break;
                    case CI_type::CI_char16:
                        {
                            BufferLength = 16;
                            char* p = new char[BufferLength + 1];
                            mem[c] = p;
                            strcpy(p, "five");
                        }
                        break;
                    case CI_type::CI_datetime:
                        {
                            SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT* p = new SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT;
                            mem[c] = p;
                            p->year = 2021;
                            p->month = 5;
                            p->day = 27;
                            p->hour = 20;
                            p->minute = 21;
                            p->second = 0;
                            p->fraction = 0;
                        }
                        break;
                    case CI_type::CI_text:
                        {
                            BufferLength = 100;
                            char* p = new char[BufferLength + 1];
                            mem[c] = p;
                            strcpy(p, "five");
                        }
                        break;
                    case CI_type::CI_money:
                        {
                            BufferLength = 10;
                            char* p = new char[BufferLength + 1];
                            mem[c] = p;
                            strcpy(p, "555.55");
                        }
                        break;
                    case CI_type::CI_varchar171:
                        {
                            BufferLength = 171;
                            char* p = new char[BufferLength + 1];
                            mem[c] = p;
                            strcpy(p, "five");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    ParameterValuePtr = mem[c];
                }
                else {
                    SQLLEN* p = new SQLLEN;
                    mem[c] = p;
                    *p = SQL_NULL_DATA;
                    StrLen_or_IndPtr = p;
                }
                rc = SQLBindParameter(StatementHandle, ParameterNumber, InputOutputType, ValueType, ParameterType, ColumnSize, DecimalDigits, ParameterValuePtr, BufferLength, StrLen_or_IndPtr);
                rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, rc, "SQLBindParameter");
            } // for

            rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"{call [sp_TTemporalAccounts_ins](?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}", SQL_NTS);
            rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, rc, "SQLExecDirect()");

            for (int c = 0; c < N_COL; c++) {
                delete mem[c];
            }
        } // for
    } // for

#if 0
    // Table has (int, datetime, text, datetime)
    // Did not fail like expected

    SQLINTEGER null = SQL_NULL_DATA;
    //      rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, 23, 3, 0, 0, &null);
    //      rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, rc, "SQLBindParameter()");

    //      rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"{call [sp_TTemporalAccounts_ins](?)}", SQL_NTS);
    //      rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, rc, "SQLExecDirect()");
            // SQLcancel
    SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT ts;
    ts.year = 2021;
    ts.month = 5;
    ts.day = 27;
    ts.hour = 20;
    ts.minute = 21;
    ts.second = 0;
    ts.fraction = 0;

    rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, 23, 3, &ts, 0, 0);
    rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, rc, "SQLBindParameter()");
    rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_LONGVARCHAR, 23, 3, 0, 0, &null);
    rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, rc, "SQLBindParameter()");
    rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, 23, 3, 0, 0, &null);
    rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, rc, "SQLBindParameter()");
    rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"{call [sp_TTemporalAccounts_ins](?,?,?)}", SQL_NTS);
    rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, rc, "SQLExecDirect()");

    rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, 23, 3, 0, 0, &null);
    rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, rc, "SQLBindParameter()");
    rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_LONGVARCHAR, 23, 3, 0, 0, &null);
    rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, rc, "SQLBindParameter()");
    rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, 23, 3, &ts, 0, 0);
    rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, rc, "SQLBindParameter()");
    rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"{call [sp_TTemporalAccounts_ins](?,?,?)}", SQL_NTS);
    rc = BBCheckForInfo(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, rc, "SQLExecDirect()");

    // Bindings remain in effect until the application calls SQLBindParameter again,
    // calls SQLFreeStmt with the SQL_RESET_PARAMS option,
    // or calls SQLSetDescField to set the SQL_DESC_COUNT header field of the APD to 0

#endif
}
```

Comment: `[AccountBlob] [text] NULL,`  NO NO NO NO NO! This datatype has been deprecated for almost 2 decades. The replacement is varbinary(max) - try that instead. You have at least 2 such columns.

Comment: Does the Linux ODBC driver not support text?  There are many terabytes of data in production using text.

Comment: Changing 2 text table columns and 2 text sp args to varchar(max) gets the same error.

Comment: Nott sure if it will help get an answer but I suggest you add the ODBC drivers you are using to your question as well as the Linux distro and version.

Comment: Using FreeTDS does not have the same problem.